# See a SSHFS mounted folder in a VM Share Folder in Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, virtualbox, mount

Basicly I have a virtual machine running linux.
The virtual machine Shared folder is at **/vmshare** inside the guest and **C:\vmshare** on the host.

It should be noted that inside the guest something like the following is in some init.d script, for creating the initial guest/host VM share:

```
mount -t vboxsf vmshare /vmshare
```

From the virtual machine I tried running:

```
mkdir /vmshare/remoteshare
sshfs user@remotehost:/var/www /vmshare/remoteshare
```

After that I can edit and see the files from **remotehost** inside the linux VM Guest.
But in the Windows Host Machine inside **C:\vmshare\remoteshare** there is nothing.

Is it possible to see a sshfs mounted folder inside a VM Share Mount from the host. Or is it even possible for a mounted diretory to contain another mounted directory and have it propagate up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

When you mount a file system its contents are not copied into, or linked into, or otherwise associated with the directory at the mount point. The directory is merely a useful hook to hang the new filesystem on, and the mount is an entirely in-RAM concept that is not visible to either underlying filesystem.

What you *can* do is export the directory via samba for the Windows machine to mount. Or, I think Putty on Windows can use sshfs to mount the directory directly on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.
Unfortunately putty doesn't do sshfs, there is a port of sshfs for windows but its dead and stale.
Maybe I'll use something like rsync/Unison or the samba hack instead.